# In Go, when is SyscallConn() useful on a regular *os.File?

Tags: go, file-io

I am reading some Go code (from https://github.com/KarpelesLab/reflink) which is using `SyscallConn()` (the func defined on `*os.File`):

```golang
// reflinkInternal performs the actual reflink action without worrying about fallback
func reflinkInternal(d, s *os.File) error {
    ss, err := s.SyscallConn()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    sd, err := d.SyscallConn()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    var err2, err3 error
    err = sd.Control(func(dfd uintptr) {
        err2 = ss.Control(func(sfd uintptr) {
            // int ioctl(int dest_fd, FICLONE, int src_fd);
            err3 = unix.IoctlFileClone(int(dfd), int(sfd))
        })
    })
    if err != nil {
        // sd.Control failed
        return err
    }
    if err2 != nil {
        // ss.Control failed
        return err2
    }
    if err3 != nil && errors.Is(err3, unix.ENOTSUP) {
        return ErrReflinkFailed
    }
    // err3 is ioctl() response
    return err3
}
```

In this example, are there any advantages to using these `Control()` funcs instead of just working with `d.Fd()` and `s.Fd()` directly? More generally, what is the func `func (*os.File) SyscallConn() (syscall.RawConn, error)` useful for?

Comment: Reading the same code and having the same question. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file.Fd()` returns a file descriptor AND it makes the file descriptor operate in a blocking mode (tying up a thread for blocking operations). `SyscallConn` does not do so. It was made in fact explicitly for just getting the file descriptor without making it blocking. See [this issue for more information](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24331).